# return nothing from non-void function in C

Tags: c, gcc, return, warnings

what is considered best practice in the following snippet:

```
int foo(struct data *bar, struct info bla) {
    if (!bar) {
        bla->status = 0;
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

in fact, it works fine. but i'm feeling uncomfortable with `gcc` giving me a warning.

---

here is the actual code:

```
static int pop(struct stack **stack, struct info *info) {
        int ret;
        struct stack *tmp;

        if (!*stack) {
                info->error = 0;
                return;
        }

        ret = (*stack)->data;
        tmp = *stack;
        *stack = (*stack)->next;
        free(tmp);

        return ret;
}
```

Comment: it is just this certain case, that i need no return value. in `...` there are, in fact, a couple of ints returned. which is why i can't use `void ()`.

Comment: Return the error code; in this case, you can `return 0;` for `SUCCESS` as input is not null. Return -1 or something for `NULL_POINTER` from the else.

Comment: the point is, that i don't want/need anything meaningful to be returned. i just want to sort of break out of the function call.

Comment: @guest: And what do you expect the caller to do?  It expects a return value.  If the value you return isn't meaningful because it can determine its validity via another mechanism, then just pick some arbitrary value to return.

Comment: @Artem, @Amarghosh: You should submit answers instead of comments if you want to answer the question.

Comment: It doesn't "work fine". It's UB.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Best practice is not to write code like that. If you can't return an integer of some sort at that point, you need to redesign your code. Note that the function as written **will** return a value of some sort to the calling code - you just don't know what that value will be.

The classic way round this is to return the value via a pointer parameter, with the actual function returning a status:

```
int f( int * p ) {
   if ( bad ) {
       return 0;   // fail indicator
   }
   else {
      * p = 42;    // integer return value
      return 1;    // success indicator
   }
}
```

**Edit:** In the code you posted you are manipulating a stack. Popping an empty stack is undefined behaviour for all stacks I know, so you can just return any integer that takes your fancy (I would return 0) and document the behaviour.

Comment: well. in the above case i'm only concerned about the value in `info->status`, which indicate success/failure.

Comment: @guest: then why do you specify the return type as `int` in the first place?

Comment: @guest Perhaps if you posted the real code we could advise you better.

Comment: If you are only interested in success/failure, then redeclare the function to return bool - true or false.

Comment: i see what you mean. seems, like i was way too obsessed with not passing the return as an argument.

Answer (score 7):

The behaviour is undefined, and the warning is there for a good reason! Return a value, or change the function to a void function.

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that the return value **is not used for this specific case**, simply return 0. If the return value is used, then there is a serious flaw in your program logic that needs to be fixed first.

Answer (score 0):

Type `return 0;` or `return -1;` if this is error and your non error integers is positive signed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't return anything, you might think about throwing an exception, or, as already stated, redesigning your code.

Comment: Though it will be difficult to throw an exception from C.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, missed the C here, forget about the exception then!

Comment: You can throw exceptions in C, just write a C++ function which throws the exception and put it into a library. C does not care in which language the function is written and C++ exceptions are designed to co-exist with C code. Catching the exception with a similar library function might be a bit more knotty though :-)

And here's an example implementation of Try/Catch which uses setjmp/longjmp:
http://www.nicemice.net/cexcept/

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
}
```

returns 10.  The bash shell on Mac OS X confirms this.  That is, every `int` returning function returns something back, same should be true for functions that return other types as well.  If you don't return explicitly, something which you don't know of is returned.  If you are not able to return something at the end of function, try returning void to see if it breaks the code.  If it breaks, the functions needs more work, otherwise, continue using void return type.

Comment: That isn't what the OP was asking about. printf() explicitly returns the number of characters output - the OP is asking about what happens if you don't explicitly return a value.

Comment: afaik also C (C99?) allows the absence of the return statement in main, and "silently" "adds" a `return 0;` (or whatever value says success)

Comment: printf returns 10, but the return from main() is undefined. Could be 10, or any other number. You've just got dangling register crud passed back here.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider adding a third parameter which in fact would be the "return value" and instead of returning the result of the function, just return its status, which could be an `enum` for example ( and you could have "STATUS_OK", "STATUS_FAIL", "STATUS_NO_RESULT" etc...).

This will be understandable for anyone using your function and at the same time provide the desired behaviour (ie, not returning a value would mean not touching the third parameter and returning "STATUS_NO_RESULT" ).

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `info->error` to say if the function failed or not, you can return whatever you want, since the caller should ignore the return value. So you can silent the warning with `return -1`, `return 0`, `return MAGIC_NUMBER`... ...

In general however function are coded in the "opposite way": the return value says if the function succeeded or not. If all int return values are good, you can write the function so that it returns failure or success, and on success you fill the data. In your case your info struct could hold a `int data`, or you can add another arg to the func.

This way the caller can do something like

```
if ( pop(stack, info) == SUCCESS ) {
  // ...
  printf("%d\n", info->data);
} else { /* failure */
  // info->data holds no data, but info->error could be an error code, e.g.
  fprintf(stderr, "can't pop: %s\n", error_msg[info->error]);
}
```

The usage in your case is less intuitive:

```
data = pop(stack, info);
if (info->error != ERROR) {
  // data is valid
} else {
  // data is garbage and we have to say an error occurred.
}
```

BTW, you do not set `info->error` to something different by 0, so your code is potentially bugged; e.g.

```
  info->error = 0;
  data = pop(stack, info);
```

would trigger always an error even though indeed stack is ok and so data is valid.